# Word for spending lots of effort to be lazy

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word to describe a situation where someone would go out of their way to create a way to save a few seconds.

Example:

> Ben: Merry Christmas
>
> Matt: Merry Christmas bud
>
> Ryan:: Merry Christmas
>
> Walter: ^
>
> Ben: Walter don't be so lazy
>
> Walter: Should I instead write a script to check for people saying "Merry Christmas" and reply the same if 2 or more different people do it?

The point here is that it would take Walter a lot longer to write the script checking to see if two people had said *Marry Christmas* and insert an automatic reply than it would to just reply with *Merry Christmas*. That's a lot of effort to go to to avoid manually typing two little words.

What's a good term for this type of behaviour?

Comment: What you are asking is not clear and it doesn't look like somebody is spending a lot of effort to be lazy. Loat is not an English word. The following is the rule of this community. **Questions on choosing an ideal word or phrase must include information on how it will be used in order to be answered**. For help writing a good word or phrase request, see: [About single word requests](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info). Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: @Araucaria I am not the downvoter for the record. That's what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like Walter is quite the "contrarian" or you could say he's disputatious. Neither of these words perfectly fits the scenario, but they come close. Walter is not one for social norms and is willing to argue his point, with sarcasm I might add, to undermine when any of those rules are imposed on him.

I wouldn't say he's lazy though, no, not at all.